# «Мероприятий не проводилось» — верно ли?

Tags: грамматика, согласование

Как правильно указать в документе: «мероприятий по подготовке объекта не проводилось» или «мероприятия по подготовке объекта не проводились»?

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такой вариант: "Подготовка объекта была сорвана."
Оба указанных вами варианта допустимы и грамматически верны, но по своей стилистике оба - многословные, неуклюжие канцелярские штампы.